# How to make 2 different Laravel Validation messages for the same rule that has 2 different arguments?

Tags: laravel, validation

Hello I have Laravel validation request with these rules

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'unique:users,email|required|unique:invitations,email',
        'name' => 'string|required',
    ];
}
```

I want that "unique:users,email" would display one message and "unique:invitations,email" display other message. How to do that?

```
'unique:users,email' => 'This E-Mail address is already registered.',
'unique:invitations,email' => 'Invitation to this E-Mail address is already sent.',
```

It always returns default message for "unique" rule.

```
'unique' => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define like

```
'email.unique:users,emai' => ....,
'email.unique:invitations,emai' => ....,
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but can you try these

```
 public function messages()
{
    return [
      'unique:users,email' => 'This E-Mail address is already registered.',
      'unique:invitations,email' => 'Invitation to this E-Mail address is already sent.',
    //or  
    'email.unique:users,emai' => 'This E-Mail address is already registered.',
    'email.unique:invitations,email' => 'Invitation to this E-Mail address is 

    //you may even try it without the ,fieldname
    'email.unique:users' => '' 
    ];
}
```